# If i login with a user it logs in with any password

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

```html
<?php
require 'includes/common.php';
$email=$_POST['email'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
$email= mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $email);
$password= mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $password);
//md5($password);
 $select_user_query="select id , email from users where email='$email' and password= $password";
 //removed 'email' to email//
        $select_user_result= mysqli_query($con, $select_user_query) or die (mysqli_error($con));
                    
               if (mysqli_num_rows($select_user_result==0))
               {
                   echo 'There no such user ';
               }
               
               else 
               {
                   $row=mysqli_fetch_array($select_user_result);
                   $_SESSION['email']=$email;
                   $_SESSION['id']= $row[0];
                   header('location:products.php');
               }
              
               
               
?>
```

here is the code

[image: here is the login_script.php]

**

here i am geting

1. email and password from post method
2. From my login page
3. i think most of the code is right
4. If i login with a user it logs in with any password

**

Comment: where is script ?

Comment: I dont see any of your codes. please place your codes so that we can identify the error.

Comment: he posted a image which didn't get picked up by the editor.

Please edit the question with the code.

Comment: Please do not post an image of code. Edit your question and post the code instead.

Comment: I can't read that tiny text.

Comment: Is it your password in your database is encrypted or not?

Comment: no password is not encrypted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is not in the query. it is on your condition

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($select_user_result) == 0){
    echo 'No User found';
}else{
   echo 'oK';
}
```

You ca try this way. I think your error is you inserted the `==0` inside the mysqli_num_rows() it must be outside.

Comment: Oh I got it now I will update my answer please wait.

Comment: If I answer your question please accept it as the answer and thumbs up thanks. glad it help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming password is a string..

`$select_user_query="select id , email from users where email='$email' and password= $password";`
is what you wrote,

you've maybe forgotten to put single quotes around `$password` here.

Comment: added the single quotes but still... any user can log in with any password

Answer (score 0):

**Please verify this code:**

I use this code for login:

if user provides the Correct Credentials-- `If` part will work,
if not then `else` part will be work

```
<?php
 // Grab User submitted information
$user = $_POST["username"];
$pass = $_POST["password"];

//$uc_id=$_GET["user_check_id"];


// Connect to the database
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","pass123");
// Make sure we connected successfully
if(! $con)
{
    die('Connection Failed'.mysql_error());
}
// Select the database to use
mysqli_select_db($con, "login");
//$query ="SELECT user_check_id from loginpage where username='$user' and password='$pass'";
$query ="SELECT * from loginpage where username='$user' and password='$pass'";


//echo $query;

if ($query)
{
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    if($row["username"]==$user && $row["password"]==$pass)
    {
            echo "Welcome Admin";       
    }
else
        {
            echo"Please Enter the Correct Username/Password...!!";
}
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put single quotes around $password in your query and then try.